# String & StringBuffer classes in relation to append() method

Tags: java, string, append, stringbuffer

I qoute from ***Herbert Schildt*** book on ***Java***, ***Chapter String Handling***,

> The `append( )` method is most often called when the `+` operator is used on String objects.
>   Java automatically changes modifications to a String instance into similar operations on a
>   StringBuffer instance. Thus, a concatenation invokes `append( )` on a StringBuffer object.

I know very well that a concatenation invokes `append( )` on a StringBuffer instance. What does the author mean by saying "`append( )` method is most often called when the `+` operator is used on String objects"? As per my understanding 'append()' cannot be used with strings.

> After the concatenation has been performed, the compiler inserts a call to `toString( )` to turn
>   the modifiable StringBuffer back into a constant String. All of this may seem unreasonably
>   complicated. Why not just have one string class and have it behave more or less like
>   StringBuffer? The answer is performance. There are many optimizations that the Java run
>   time can make knowing that String objects are immutable. Thankfully, Java hides most of the
>   complexity of conversion between Strings and StringBuffers. Actually, many programmers
>   will never feel the need to use StringBuffer directly and will be able to express most operations
>   in terms of the + operator on String variables.

I wish to know what are the optimizations that the Java run time can make knowing that String objects are immutable?

Elaborating with a code always yields for me a better understanding for the mentioned problem?

Comment: The Java compiler will replace the + with a StringBuffer (actually now a StringBuilder) and call append.

Comment: Does he wish to say something like this                           String s1;
s1 = sb.append("a = ").append(a).append("!").toString();

Comment: The compiler would replace `String s1 = "a = " + a + "!";` with something like that; yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to know what are the optimizations that the Java run time can make knowing that String objects are immutable?

For starters, there's the string pool -- any string literals in your program will be interned; different classes that both refer to string literals with the same contents will just refer to the same object in memory.

In crazier news, there's an [option](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/string-deduplication-new-feature-java-8-update-20-2/) in recent versions of the Java garbage collector where, under certain conditions, the garbage collector will detect multiple `String` objects with the same contents and edit them to point to the same backing `char[]`.  This is only possible because Strings are immutable, and allows the garbage collector to silently (and semantics-preservingly) reduce memory consumption.